# How to change / move button position "when" clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im setting my button with :active to move it when clicked with margin-top & left, but everytime i click the button, the heading above is also move to the top, it also effect the scrollbar. How to make just the button that move?

Then, when i add margin-top to my button div, the heading above is also pushed to top, how to get rid of it so just the button who go down?

Thanks

Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/arknmaulana/ktuvq9sb/6/

```
<body>
<div class="center" id="section01">
    <div>
        <h1>Journal Online</h1>
        <p>Untuk kamu yang masih pake jurnal analog</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>GET STARTED</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#section01 div:nth-child(2):active{
box-shadow: none;
margin-top: 110px;
margin-left: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CSS transform property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) to move your button without screwing up your layout:

```css
#section01 div:nth-child(2):active{
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: translate(10px, 20px);
}
```

Comment: could also define transition, to set the animation type and duration